# Cannot get user to select account before login using facebook socialite

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-socialite

I'm using socialite for facebook login but the issue is if i'm already login in facebook account then before login it should force user to select pop up this code is working for google login but i want it in facebook login also which is not working.

```
public function facebookRedirect()
    {
        return Socialite::driver('facebook')->with(["prompt" => "select_account"])->redirect();
    }
```

Any suggestions. Thanks